Metadata / schemas for HtmlContent1
I am struggling to find an official schema/metadata/EDMX description of the data contained in a SharePoint page's HtmlContent1 or JsonContent1, for example:
{
    "controlType": 4,
    "id": "b954b48f-37df-4a13-8012-a389508ce7a5",
    "position": {
        "controlIndex": 0.5,
        "sectionIndex": 2,
        "sectionFactor": 8,
        "zoneIndex": 1,
        "layoutIndex": 1
    },
    "emphasis": {
        "zoneEmphasis": 0
    },
    "addedFromPersistedData": true,
    "zoneGroupMetadata": {
        "type": 0
    }
}

Here is what I have figured out so far:

The HtmlContent1 returned e.g. from /_api/web/lists('<GUID of SitePages>')/items(<id>) has embedded JSON that is equivalent to the HtmlContent1/JsonContent1 returned by /_api/sitepages/pages(<id>).
The EDMX description under /_api/web/$metadata contains a description of an SP.SitePagesItem (returned by the _api/web/lists endpoint) as well as a description of SP.Publishing.SitePage (returned by /_api/sitepage). However, both describe HtmlContent1 as a String with no additional information.
I searched for some of the fields from the above example in the output of /_api/web/$metadata but came out empty-handed.
The v2 beta API contains an endpoint for the contents of a SharePoint page (under /_api/v2.1/sites('<GUID>')/pages/<GUID>/oneDrive.page?$expand=canvasLayout), and there is a schema/metadata description under /_api/v2.1/$metadata. However, due to multiple technical limitations cannot use this endpoint, and the descriptions are not compatible.

My question is: Have I missed something? Or do I need to reconstruct the structure from examples?
Thanks in advance!
